# cellを左にスワイプさせ「削除ボタン」と「詳細ボタン」を表示させたい

Tags: swift, tableview

cellを左にスワイプし、「削除ボタン」と「詳細ボタン」を表示させ、cellの削除と詳細ページへの遷移をしたいです。

削除ボタンは、以下のコードを書いて、成功しました。

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
      dataList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
     testTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
 } }
```

ですが、詳細ボタンの付け方と詳細ボタンを押した時の画面遷移のコードがわかりません。
理想完成図は、以下の画像です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `UITableViewRowAction`でネット検索すると、お求めになっている情報が集まるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @nagonsoftware 結構探してみたものの、あまり良い情報が集まらなくて、手こずっております。。

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewDelegate`のメソッド`tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)`を利用します。`UITableViewRowAction`クラスについて、リファレンスでお調べください。
サンプルコードを載せておきます。テーブルの設定は、Storyboard上で行なっている前提になっています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    // UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No. \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    // UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Detail"){ action, indexPath in
            // Do anything
        }

        return [action]
    }

}
```

`// Do Anything`の箇所に、ボタンをタップした時の処理を記述します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Detailボタンを押した時に、詳細ページに遷移できるようにしたいのですが、（詳細ページはストーリーボードで作成してあります）//Do anything の部分に書くべきコードも教えてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: 別トピックの話題になりますから、新規に画面遷移の話題として、質問を立ててください。（すでに質問者さんは、新規に質問をなさっているようですが）